# Menu button dropdown text behind other menu buttons.

Tags: w3.css

When creating some [clickable dropdowns](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_dropdown_click), I noticed the dropdown menu will hide behind any clickable dropdown buttons if they overlap. Here is an example

[image: W3.CSS Clickable Dropdown]

How can I fix this? Here is the code used to create the dropdown.

```
<div class="w3-container">
  <div class="w3-dropdown-click">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="w3-btn">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="Demo" class="w3-dropdown-content w3-border">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also made a fiddle, but it doesn't seem to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/99d8d7pj/

BTW, would this be considered a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: This could be to do with your z-index, can you provide your css for the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Tony Hensler's comment, it was the z-index.

```
<div id="<?php echo $course->course_id; ?>" class="w3-dropdown-content w3-border" style="right:0; z-index:1;">
```

I just added `z-index:1` to the w3-dropdown-content div as an inline style for the fix.

Thanks Tony.